# Liferay: Instanceable portlet company-wide preferences

Tags: layout, liferay, portlet, preferences

Is there any way to get 2 instances of an instanceable portlet with different preferences, be shared across all layouts for each one?

I mean portlet A Instance 1  is placed in all communities and it shares preferences for all layouts where it is placed

Portlet A Instance 2 is placed in a subset of those communities and it shares preferences for all layouts where it is placed

Or maybe is it that the relation between a portlet and its image in another layout is exactly the same as the relation between 2 instances in same page (no connected at all)?

Its a bit confusing telling between per-page instance and per-layout instance then.

Is it the last option totally duplicate portlet and set company-wide preferences for each instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding as answer:

With such a complex requirement, it may be best to "cheat" and declare two instances of the same portlet in the portlet.xml and liferay-portlet.xml so you can control the preferences independently

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.0/definitions/liferay-portlet-app_6_0_0.dtd.html#preferences-unique-per-layout as it has a good discussion of `preferences-unique-per-layout` and `preferences-owned-by-group` and how they interact with each other

Comment: Thanks! I already read a lot about these issues.  In that case, company-wide makes both option be ignored. The clue here is that portlet is instanceable, but company-wide.

Comment: With such a complex requirement, it may be best to "cheat" and declare two instances of the same portlet in the portlet.xml and liferay-portlet.xml so you can control the preferences independently

Comment: To define the portlet twice is the easiest (and probably the cleanest) way to achieve this.

Comment: Really nice idea! Could you add it to the answer so I can accept it?! thanks!